# WSDL-XSD to PL\SQL

Tags: plsql, xsd, wsdl, xsd2code, wsdl2code

Hers my problem:
we have a web service that we need to invoke from PL\SQL. I want a tool similar to this http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlDataBinding/Xml-Schema-To-VB.aspx, only for PL\SQL.
In java, you can pass the WSDL file and the API will generate classes and methods required to implement that web service on the client side. is there anything similar for PL\SQL.I want to pass the WSDL url to a tool and get the PL\SQL procedures and function required to implement that web service on the client side, which in my case is using Oracle forms as his main system.
to put it in another way, I want an easy way to create the client side code to consume my web service without having to do all the work of converting WSDL to Soap and then recreating the soap as text and send it through utl_http to the server and then rendering the soap response and getting the required value.
i.e. if i convert the object described by WSDL to PL\SQL object. then i can create the XML transmitted between server-client like this :

```
person.setname('Test');    //this should be PL\SQL code;
person.setaddress('Somewhere');    //this should be PL\SQL code;
person.setage(25);    //this should be PL\SQL code;
xml.send_as_xml(person);   //this should be PL\SQL code;
```

where person is the object i want to send from client to server. and person object skeleton was created by the tool that im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much research i found out that it is better to write your code in JAVA and load the java class to the data base. JDeveloper was a good resource to help me do that.